# Rails 4: Devise - Admin to approve user on sign up - strong params for approved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4. I use devise and omniauth.

I am trying to follow this tutorial.  http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

I have had to make some changes to the setup to get it working and because I want to have certain users approving users on registration.

I am trying to understand the devise documentation for this process.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

In particular:

The docs issue a warning about adding :approved to the strong params - as: WARNING: Adding 'approved' as whitelisted parameter in strong params could allow any user to approve itself by adding an input tag in the registrations form. Take actions to manage.

I have listed :approved in my strong params as follows:

```
def user_params
      accessible = [ :first_name, :last_name, :email ] # extend with your own params
      accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
      accessible << [:approved] if user.admin
      params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
    end
```

Only a user that is an admin can access this attribute. Is this the kind of action that the warning is suggesting? If not, how do you protect this?

When I try running the server, I get a message saying something went wrong. The heroku logs say:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `approved?' for #<User:0x007f498741c210>):
2015-12-12T00:20:22.048675+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:130:in `active_for_authentication?'
```

I try adding a method called 'approved' as:

```
def approved
    self.approved = true
  end
```

I still have this in my user model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
    super && approved?
  end
```

But I still get the same error. I don't understand what's going wrong.